# why Context.RewritePath method not work on iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, iis-7

I have an asp.net3.5 website.want to deploy this site on iis.After deploy my default page can not redirect to another page.Need help to understand why page not redirect 
My default page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Response.Write("hello")
      Context.RewritePath("~/asp/Default.aspx", False)


    End Sub
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Need help why Context.RewritePath this method not working.my server version is windows server 2008 r2,iis-7.0 ,web site develop on 3.5

If have any query plz ask ,thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be in your globals.acsx page, under begin_request